# I'm new to c# but what is wrong here

Tags: search, browser

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.m_keyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And what actually happens when you run this code?

Comment: Is the Form `KeyPreview` property set to `True`?